# Help in translation of '그런줄 알았더니 후렴구는 또 멋있고'

Tags: translation

그런줄 알았더니 후렴구는 또 멋있고

Can you please translate this?

I know its something about a chorus but can't put it together .

EDIT (from OP comment):
Context: There's a song playing and the person comments about it, seemingly describing a quality about the singer himself because after it he says that he learned that the singer has more aspects to him. From what i understood he says something like " i thought the chorus is cool too "

Comment: Is there any more context you can provide?

Comment: Context: There's a song playing and the person comments about it, seemingly describing a quality about the singer himself because after it he says that he learned that the singer has more aspects to him. From what i understood he says something like " i thought the chorus is cool too "

Comment: @Connie that seems to agree with my answer!

Answer (score 1):

'그런줄 알았더니' = 'that's what I thought, and then...' or 'when I thought that...'

'후렴구' is a chorus or refrain, as you say.

멋있어 = to be good or well-formed.

'또' usually means 'again', but it can also be used in the sense of 'also' or 'moreover'.

So altogether it could be something like 'I was thinking that (it was nice), then the chorus was good too'.

Comment: It cannot be '도', because '도' and '은/는' cannot occur together. I think '또' is correct here: it's probably used just for emphasis.  Something like, "...but **then again** the refrain is great!"

Comment: @jick I've asked my Korean and edited accordingly... what do you think? Or does ''그런줄 알았더니" have a contrastive meaning?

Comment: The sentence is very conversational, so it's difficult to guess the exact intention without knowing what came before/after that.  But at least to me, "그런 줄 알았더니" sounds like contrast.  E.g., "I had thought (the song would suck), but then (when I heard it) I found the chorus great."